# How to create a new page in notion and create a block table under the new page?

Tags: python, api, notion-api

I tried to do this but because the new page created was empty, it couldn't be recognized. I also tried to create a blank block, but it still couldn't be solved.

> How to solve this situation, I want to create a block type table under the new page

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQY6y.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWQp9.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.